# Issue Sending to Distribution List in Python

Tags: python, email, report, mutt

I have a report that I run everyday that I'm trying to send to a distribution list but am having one minor issue that is causing a big problem since it's not being sent to the appropriate people. It appears that if I try to send the report to a distribution list with periods in the address, the report won't send. Otherwise, it sends fine.

If I send the report to a single email such as "`myname@domain.com`" it works.

If I send the report to a distribution list such as "`ME-EXAMPLE-EAMPLE2@domain.com`" it also works.

However, the distribution list I am sending it to has periods in it. I.E "`ME.EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE2@domain.com`" and this will not work

The only thing I can think of is that python is having a issue parsing the periods. Has anyone else ran into this problem or found a solution to it?

```
def sendEmail(parser):
    email = 'ME.EXAMPLE.EXAMPLE2.ME@gmail.com'
    dailyReportLocation = parser.get('FileLocations','dailyReport')
    yearlyReportLocation = parser.get('FileLocations','yearlyReport')
    blankFile = parser.get('FileLocations','blankEmailContentFile')

    fh = open(blankFile, 'w+')
    fh.close()

    linuxCMD = 'mutt -s "Daily & Yearly Hang Report" -a %s -a %s "%s" < %s ' % (dailyReportLocation,yearlyReportLocation,email,blankFile)

    #print(linuxCMD)
    os.system(linuxCMD)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    c = ConfigurationPreCheck()
    parser = c.run()
    scrubbedFile = scrubPreviousDayReport(parser,getPreviousDayReportName(parser))
    runReport(parser,DAILY_REPORT)
    runReport(parser,YEARLY_REPORT)
    sendEmail(parser)
```

Comment: How are you sending the email?

Comment: Can you include the code that you're using to send the email? Without the code, I don't think it's possible to identify what the actual problem may be.

Comment: Question updated with code.

Comment: Have you tried calling mutt directly from the command line to see if it works?